# Neither sortBy nor filterBy of p:column are working inside composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

Simply I have composite component of datatable using primefaces 4.0 the rendered output had no sorting facility nor filtering (i.e. column header has no arrows for sort and there is no input for filter field); my code as below

```
<composite:implementation> <p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.objectList}" var="item" resizableColumns="true" draggableColumns="true" paginator="true" 
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rows="10"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150" editable="true" editMode="cell" lazy="true" >

    <c:if test="#{!empty cc.attrs.column1Value }">
        <p:column sortBy="#{item[cc.attrs.column1Value]}"  filterBy="#{item[cc.attrs.column1Value]}" headerText="#{cc.attrs.column1Label}" rendered="#{empty cc.attrs.column1InputList}">
                #{item[cc.attrs.column1Value]}
        </p:column>
    </c:if>
```

I tried to change the value of sort by to be `sortBy=#{cc.attrs.colum1Value}` the sorting arrows appears but it doesn't work ... I'm using Jboss 6.1 Final GA, primefaces 4.0, Mojarra-2.0, jsf-impl-2.0.3-b05.jar. I appreciate your support to get sorting and filtering work inside composite component

Comment: You're using view build-time JSTL (`c:if`) inside a view render-time (`p:dataTable`) component. Your `item` variable isn't available when `c:if` is evaluated.

Comment: Right, however JSTL works inside composite component

Comment: Can you describe your use case a bit more? Sounds like you want to hide the column when `column1Value` isn't set. Why can't you roll this check into the `rendered` attribute?

Comment: The column is rendered without filter field nor sort arrows :( after updating sortBy as mentioned above the sort arrows appears in the table header and clickable but without change. you can ignore both `c:if` and `rendered` I just toke them copy & paste there is another code that I didn't add

Comment: @mabi: The `<c:if>` isn't testing the `#{item}`. Your argument would otherwise indeed be valid.